# SQL iaas, change version will reflect bill changes?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We have a SQL Server 2012 enterprise VM on azure, we found it is a bit expensive so we decide to go back to standard, since the VM is already provisioned and configured, we thought the easiest way is to uninstall the SQL Server Enterprise, then download and install SQL Server standard from MSDN.

Question, will this reflect the billing change, which is the goal? Nor we have to provision a new standard instance from gallery. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not reflect the billing change. You will need to provision a new standard SQL from the gallery and then employ one of the migration techniques enumerated here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156165.aspx#move) to migrate the sql data to the newly provisioned VM.

Comment: thanks, very interesting, I got mixed answers here, I emailed the MS support, this is what he says 'Once the changes is made the bill will be back to standard rates.
But for whatever was the prior usage it will be billed according to the usage.',my question to him is 'so it is ok we uninstall the enterprise SQL, download then install the standard version from msdn, the billing will back to bill by standard rate, right? Just to confirm'